# How build an Electron 9 app with Angular 9?

Tags: angular, npm, electron

I've tried multiple ways to build an **Electron** app using Angular 9 and somehow it fails to build in any of those ways and for the tutorial person showing-off it kind of works.
Has anyone done it before in debian?
If yes I'd like to see how you achieved it.

Comment: What does it fail on? What tutorial did you follow? Do you want to build it as is or using some build tools?

Comment: Well I tried this on linux: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mr9Mtm_TRpw
and didnt work!
I'd like to know the right way to build it, if it doesnt work then any work-around that.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron

Comment: Thank you @dallows ! 
The resource was really helpfull!